# Direction number of curve whose points lie on the tangents of another curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $X^i = x^i +ua^i $ be parametric equations of the tangent to a curve C at $x^i$ (where $a^i$ are the direction cosines of the tangent at $x^i$ to C).

Let s be the arc distance along C from a specific point. If u is replaced by a function of s, the resulting equations are equations of a curve D whose points lie on the tangents of C.

A text that I am reading claims that $\frac {dX^i}{ds} $ are direction numbers of D. However, I thought this could only be true if s parameterized arc distance along D, and it is not obvious to me how that is the case. Is the text in error or am I in error, and if the latter is the case, how so?

Comment: It seems that the definition of "direction numbers" is at stake here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let s' be the arc distance along D from some particular point. $ s' = \int \sqrt{\sum(\frac{dX^i}{dt})^2} dt $ for any parameterisation t of D.

Note that $\frac{dX^i}{ds'}$ are the direction cosines of D.

Now $ \frac{dX^i}{ds'} = \frac{dX^i}{ds}\frac{ds}{ds'}$.

$ \frac{ds}{ds'} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum(\frac{dX^i}{ds})^2}} $

So  $ \frac{dX^i}{ds'} =  \frac{\frac{dX^i}{ds}}{\sqrt{\sum(\frac{dX^i}{ds})^2}}$

Note that the factor $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum(\frac{dX^i}{ds})^2}}$ merely normalises $\frac{dX^i}{ds}$. Therefore $\frac{dX^i}{ds}$ and $\frac{dX^i}{ds'} $ are parallel; they only differ in length. Therefore  $ \frac{dX^i}{ds}$ are legitimate direction numbers of D at $X^i$.